# Javascript file keeps "loading" forever

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

I have used document.write to write script tag to include a js file on a remote server. I also already used the createElement tag for the same purpose.
But when I'm debugging the network I see the GET request to fetch .js file on server but it keeps like that and does not end.
[image: Method GET without any return code. keeps like that forever]

So tested like this:

```
document.write("<script type=\"application/javascript\" src=\"https://domain.tld/file.js\"><\/script>");
```

If I access via browser I got the .js file. I have not idea what's going on.
Can't it be apache config file? Like .htaccess misconfiguration. I just have a expiration default for caching purposes:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
```

Comment: remove the `type` or use correct one

Comment: If I remove the type it will know what type of script it will be to execute right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was an external program I used to filter the clients that just crashed.
Thats why it shows as 0KB without any return code (200 or 500 for internal error).